# Maven Archetype - How to decide generate a file or not according to a property?

Tags: java, maven, archetypes

With Maven Archetype, how to generate a file or not according to a property.
e.g:
If user input prop.use.redis as true while execute "mvn archetype:create", do generate redis.xml, otherwise ignore redis.xml.
`

```
if (${prop.use.redis} == true) {
   generateFile("src/main/resources/redis.xml");
}
else {
   System.out.println("do not need generate src/main/resources/redis.xml");
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Six years later, I found a way to implement this: use "archetype-post-generate.groovy" to create file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).